# GMock std::any argument

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have an interface

```
class IUObject {
public:
    virtual void setProperty(const std::string& name, const std::any& value) = 0;
    virtual void setProperty(const std::string& name, std::any&& value) = 0;
};
```

I`ve created mock object:

```
class MockUObject : public IUObject {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, setProperty, (const std::string& name, const std::any& value), (override));
    MOCK_METHOD(void, setProperty, (const std::string& name, std::any&& value), (override));
};
```

I need to test `setProperty` function via `EXPECT_CALL`.
I`ve tried something like this:

```
MockUObject *mock = new MockUObject();
/// Some code here
EXPECT_CALL(*mock, setProperty(TypedEq<const std::string&>("position"),
                               TypedEq<std::any&&>(std::any(std::pair<double, double>(6.0, 2.0)))));
```

But compiler cant compare `std::any`:

```
error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'const std::any' and 'const std::any')
```

I cant change base interface functions, so i have to work with `std::any`. How can i deal with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no matcher for `std::any`, so you need to write your own.

```
MATCHER_P(AnyMatcher, value, "")
{
    // assume the type of parameter is the same as type stored in std::any, 
    // will not work e.g. when any stores std::string and you pass a literal
    // you'd need to write a template matcher for that case
    return std::any_cast<decltype(value)>(arg) == value;
}
```

Usage:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*mock, setProperty(TypedEq<const std::string&>("position"),
                               AnyMatcher(std::pair<double, double>(6.0, 2.0))));
```

[See it online](https://godbolt.org/z/9Prcn83cM) (and a [passing case](https://godbolt.org/z/cvd7ozYYh)). Note that you cannot really have overloads where one function has `const` lvalue reference as argument and the other rvalue reference, because that's ambiguous (both can accept rvalue as argument).

Comment: Here's an attempt at templated solution, but I'm not good enough with templates to tell if this will work in general case (or if it actually does what is needed): https://godbolt.org/z/fbWfn1zc9